# Sql query Where Clause X in Y

Tags: mysql, sql

I have trouble with where clause

Table

```
X  Y
-- --
1  10
1  15
1  20
0  10
0  20
0  40
0  50
```

I want to select all X but where X=0 the Y only >20
because all value Y where X=1 is <20
so the result would be

result table

```
X  Y
-- --
1  10
1  15
1  20
0  40
0  50
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tablename 
WHERE (X = 0 AND Y > 20) OR (X = 1 AND Y < 20)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME 
WHERE (X = 1 AND Y<=20) OR (X=0 AND Y>20);
```